# How many Jedi use red lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, lightsaber

We know some Jedi use red Lightsabers, but I'd like to know who all of them are.

I know Adi Gallia originally used a red blade.

Comment: Typically, Sith or former Sith use red. Jedi don't.

Comment: How is this "non-constructive"? Granted it's not a great question, but it's not "non-constructive" in the least.

Comment: Because it's a list question.

Answer (score 7):

Adi Gallia was the only explicit example of a Jedi wielder of a red lightsaber that was not Dark/Sith-turned.

The reason there were very Jedi with red lightsabers was because Jedi had issues not with the color, but with the technology: most red crystals were [synthetic ones](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Synthetic_lightsaber_crystal), and their creation was mostly possible using Dark Side of the Force.

However, natural red crystals also occurred, though rarely, and those COULD be used by Jedi:

> Not all red lightsaber crystals were synthetic. Adegan crystals featuring a red coloration were not unheard of, Darth Vader utilizing such a crystal in one of his lightsabers, and red-hued crystals were known to form naturally in the Crystal Caves on Dantooine, along with blue, green, yellow and violet crystals. However, unlike the other crystals, the red crystals from Dantooine were typically found in unhatched kinrath eggs.

---

[image]

(source:  http://iharthdarth.livejournal.com/2867.html)

Dialogue:

```
Hooded Figure: Save your wife.
Brat: mmmm.

Hooded figure: Phenomenal cosmic power.
Brat: mmmm.

... deep silence

Hooded figure: ... red lightsaber?

Brat: OMG. Sign me up!!!
```

Comment: Luke created his lightsaber using green synthetic crystals, so I wouldn't be so eager to say that such crystals require the dark side of the force to create, even for red ones.

Comment: @Dungarth - true. Was Luke actually creating the crystal?

Comment: @DVK in [Shadows of the Empire (novel)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shadows_of_the_Empire_%28novel%29), Luke created his lightsaber crystal using a device (an oven?) in [Ben's hut](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ben_Kenobi%27s_hut#History).

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Synthetic_lightsaber_crystal

Comment: @bitmask:BTW, +25/-6. Your argument is invalid (incert Slytherincess' random macro)

Comment: Ferus Olin used a red blade as an Apprentice